# Programa para saber si un numero es multiplo de 10

Tags: java, bucle-for

**Se que hay otra maneras muchísimo mas eficaces para resolver este problema, pero quiero intentar todas las posibles para practicar un poco**

*El caso es el siguiente, una de las soluciones que pensé fue esta:*

```
int valor = 13;

valor = valor + 10;

if(valor == 20){

  System.out.println("Es multiplo de 10");

} else{

  System.out.println("No es multiplo de 10");

}
```

**Básicamente, Un número es múltiplo de 10 si contiene a 10 varias veces exactamente. 50 es múltiplo de 10, ya que contiene a 10 cinco veces**

*En el ejemplo de arriba, 13, no es múltiplo de 10, porque su suma no da un numero exacto, por eso no lo es*

**Así que eso es lo que intento hacer**

**Lo que intento hacer con el for es lo siguiente:**

```
J = 10;
for(int i = 0; i >= J; i++){
//Si N es mayor a J,como por ejemplo 13, entonces el bucle hara que J se sume 10 mas
if(number > J){
    J = J + 10;

  } else {

    number = number + 10;

    if(number == J){
      System.out.println("Es multiplo");

    } else{
      System.out.pritnln("No es multiplo");

    }
  }
}
```

**Luego de que pase por el bucle, ahora J se sumara 10 mas, siguiendo el ejemplo con el 13:**

```
J = 10;
for(int i = 0; i >= j; i++){
// Ahora J vale 20

if(number > J){
    J = J + 10;

  } else {
    //ahora number se sumara 10
    number = number + 10;

    //13 + 10 = 23, entonces number no es igual a J
    if(number == J){
      System.out.println("Es multiplo");

    } else{
      //13 no es multiplo de 10
      System.out.pritnln("No es multiplo");

    }
  }
}
```

**Este es el código con el que pensé hacerlo**

```
 public void ten() {
        int j = 10;
        //Si Number es igual a 10, entonces es multiplo
        if (this.number == j || this.number == 1) {

            System.out.println("Es multiplo de 10");
        //Si no es igual a 10, y es menor a 10, entonces no es múltiplo de 10, como por ejemplo el 5
        } else if (this.number < j) {

            System.out.println("No es multiplo de 10");
        
        } else{
        //si el numero es mayor a 10 entonces entra al for
            for (int i = 0; i >= j; i++) {
                //Si number es mayor a J, entonces j sumara otra mas y volvera al bucle
                if (this.number >= j) {
                    j = j + 10;

                    //si no es mayor, entonces entrara al else
                } else {

                   //si el numero es por ejemplo 20, entonces se sumara a 10, si es igual a j, es multiplo de 10
                    this.number = this.number + 10;

                    if (this.number == j) {

                        System.out.println("Es multiplo de 10");
                        i = j;

                    } else {

                        System.out.println("No es multiplo de 10");
                        i = j;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**El problema es que no entra al Bucle y no tengo ni idea de porque. He mirado muchas veces y aun no comprendo porque no entra al Bucle, si me pueden ayudar seria de gran ayuda, muchas gracias de antemano**

Comment: Buenas, te recomiendo realizar el [tour] para que puedas ver como realizar una pregunta de calidad. Añades bastante código redundante, supongo que son partes para explicar el ultimo, pero con indicarlo todo y explicar con comentarios en código o por texto bastaría. También indicarte que muchas condiciones tanto del bucle como de los if están mal planteadas, ejemplo if (number == j || number == 1) y tienes la variable j asignada en vez de pedirla siempre será true, pero si pides al usuario el valor de j entonces la parte de number == 1 será siempre false, y no entrara en el if.

Comment: También el ejemplo esta mal planteado, al menos yo no entiendo de donde sacas el number, en el ultimo código dices en comentario que number es igual a 10, pero yo ahí veo la variable j es igual a 10, number veo la variable pero no donde se crea y que valor tiene. Insisto en la recomendación de que edites y pongas tu código completo, en una sola explicación.

Comment: Te estas complicando la vida. Un numero es multiplo de 10 si al dividirlo entre 10 el residuo es 0.

Answer (score 0):

No entra al `for` porque el valor de `i` siempre es 0 y el de `j` es siempre 10, es decir que la condición `i >= j` nunca se cumple. En realidad la variable `j` no tiene ninguna razón de ser. Lo que estas intentando hacer es esto:

```
void ten() {
    boolean isMultiple = this.number == 1;
    for (int i = 10; number >= i; i = i + 10) {
        if (this.number == i) {
            isMultiple = true;
        }
    }
    if (isMultiple) {
        System.out.println("Es multiplo de 10");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No es multiplo de 10");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Como has dicho en el principio, hay maneras más sencillas de hacerlo. Pero antes, vayamos a tu fallo en concreto.

Cuando inicializamos variables siempre hay que llevar cuidado al ponerlas como condición en un bucle. En este caso, en tu bucle for la variable **i** no va actualizar su valor nunca (inicialmente es 0), dado que has **j** tiene el valor de 10 y la condición de iteración es **i>=j**.

Por otro lado, hay una manera mucho más eficiente de hacer esta comprobación, que es con el módulo (operador **%**). Un número A será múltiplo de un número B si A % B == 0. Te muestro un ejemplo de código para múltiplos de 10.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    
    static void multiplo(int numberA, int numberB){
        if(numberA % numberB == 0)
            System.out.println(numberA + " es multiplo de " + numberB);
        else
            System.out.println(numberA + " NO es multiplo de " + numberB);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       multiplo(5, 10);
       multiplo(10,10);
       multiplo(120, 10);
       multiplo(121,10);
    }
}
```